# Listening to Swift events in Javascript; React Native Native Modules

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, react-native

I am trying to figure out how my Javascript code can listen to my native modules events that are being emitted from my Swift code in my React Native app. I cannot seem to find any official documentation and anything I find after a Google search is either outdated or is written in Obj-C whereas my event is fired from my Swift code. I hope that makes sense and any help would be appreciated!

Thanks, Aiden

Answer (score 0):

It's actually described in quite a detail [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#sending-events-to-javascript).

1. First you create an Objective-C bridge to catch events from Swift.
2. Then in Objective-C again, you implement an `RCTEventEmitter` (can be same or different class) This is the class that will send events to JS. The events are sent using `sendEventWithName` function

Here's a very rough sketch:

Step 1: catch Swift events

```
@interface MyBridge() <SomeDelegate>

@end

@implementation MyBridge

// Here's my delegate function:
- (void)myDelegateCalled 
     // Received an event
     // Calling bridge to send the event to JS
     BridgeEventEmitter send:someData
     ...
```

Step 2: send them to JS

```
// Here's the BridgeEventEmitter:
@interface BridgeEventEmitter : RCTEventEmitter <RCTBridgeModule>
@end

@implementation BridgeEventEmitter
+ (void)send:(NSString *)something
{
  [self sendEventWithName:@"EventName" body:something];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can emit an event in custom swift code and then catch it in your react native code. I might be wrong. maybe consider local storage or server-side storage?